# Xamarin Forms Java.Interop error while debugging on IPad Mini

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app that I am trying to debug on I Pad mini connected to a Mac Book Pro.

Using Versions

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01055

Installed Version: Community

Xamarin 4.1.1.3 (34a92cd)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.Android 6.1.1.1 (7db2aac)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.iOS 9.8.1.4 (3cf8aae)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS.

The Mac Book Pro is running Simulator 9.3.

When I use the emulator the application runs fine, but when I try and run it on The Ipad Mini I get the Error

```
 Error      Failed to resolve assembly: 'Java.Interop, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'Client.UI.iOS  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets   681
```

It makes me want to point the finger at Newtonsoft.Json but we have tried to remove that (which is required) and it still doen't work

[image: UI Project]

[image: Macx Project References]

This doesn't happen on all Apps, but now it will start to be a blocker as I need to write functions that require the use of the camera.

**** UPDATE ****

My College came back from holiday and discovered that it was because in the UI project we had a reference to Mono.Android,k removing this fixed the build

Comment: Seems like something got mixed up because you shouldn't get any Java stuff while working on iOS.

Comment: tell me about it ! Spent 3 days trying to resolve

Answer (score 0):

This is irritating I know! I faced this too

are you dealing with `JSON data`? try to comment it and run to locate the exact line where you get the error.

Probably you are dealing with it in a wrong way or any other java object.

Comment: It will NOT complle, we are using JSON data, is this not allowed on an IPAD ? It works on the emulator though, just not when I connect a iPAD